# How to run scripts in parallel on Windows

Tags: shell, command-line

On linux or Mac, regularly run several python scripts (or other programs, for that matter) in parallel. A use case could be that the script runs a simulation based on random numbers, and I just want to run it many times to get good statistics.

An easy way of doing this on linux or Mac would be to use a for loop, and use an ampersand `&` to make the jobs run in parallel:

```
for i in {1..10}; do python script.py & ; done
```

Another usecase would be that I want to run a script on some stored data in a file. Say I have a bunch of .npy files with stored data, and I want to process them all with the same script, running 4 jobs in parallel (since I have a 4-core CPU), I could use `xargs`:

```
ls *.npy | xargs -P4 -n1 python script.py
```

Are there equivalent ways of doing this on the Windows command line?

Comment: Yes check out [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start)

Comment: I checked out start, and it looks like ```start /b``` can solve my first case, but what about the second?

Comment: Maybe SuperUser is the better platform to ask this on, there are also answers already: https://superuser.com/questions/232225/multithreaded-windows-for-batch-command